# Algorithm that can sum 4 digits in pairs so that their sum difference would be as close as possible

Tags: c++, algorithm, if-statement, simplify

I have homework in `C++` that requires me to enter `4` natural numbers and pair them so that the difference between their sum would be as low as possible.

Example:

```
I have entered 4 numbers: 4; 3; 2; 1;
The smallest between the numbers would be 0 --> 4 + 1 and 3 + 2
```

I have written some code using if statements, but to check every combination takes a lot of code to write, so I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do this task

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    int x, y, z;

    cout << "Insert 1st number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Insert 2nd number" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Insert 3rd number" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "Insert 4th number" << endl;
    cin >> d;

    if ((a > b) && (b > c) && (c > d))
    {
        x = a + d;
        y = b + c;
        z = x - y;

        cout << "The smallest differnce is: " << z << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if ((a > b) && (b > c) && (c < d))
    {
        x = a + c;
        y = b + d;
        z = x - y;
        cout << "The smallest differnce is: " << z << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if ((a > b) && (b < c) && (c > d))
    {
        x = a + b;
        y = d + c;
        z = x - y;
        cout << "The smallest differnce is: " << z << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how does your code looks like? also, where does `0` come from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Solving

Comment: @PhoenixBlue I added the code. It is not complete, but I hope you get the idea. 0 comes from adding up those 4 numbers in pairs: 4+1 = 5  and 3 + 2 = 5 and their difference is 0

Answer (score 4):

If it is only `4` natural numbers, do the following.

- First of all, create a normal array(i.e. `int[4]` or) an `std::array<int, 4>` and get the user input to it.
- Sort the array ascending(or descendingly).
- The difference between the (1<sup>st</sup> + 4<sup>th</sup>) elements and (2<sup>th</sup> + 3<sup>th</sup>) elements
  gives the result.

Here is the example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>     // std::array
#include <algorithm> // std::sort

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> arr;
    for (int& element : arr) std::cin >> element;
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    int result = (arr[0] + arr[3]) - (arr[1] + arr[2]);
    std::cout << "The smallest difference is: " << result << "\n";
}
```

**([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8QpTsaa8gFOt1wjp))**

Comment: Why is that the answer?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I thought it is self-explanatory. Hmm.. to be honest, I don't know how to explain other than from the op's example given above. I found this case is true for an array with 4 numbers.

Comment: Yes, I found this to be the answer as well but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: There are 6 cases that it can be, one just has to show 5 of those are not optimal.

Comment: @NeilEdelman But how can one make a proof that this is always the answer.

Comment: `C(4,2)=6` but half consist of taking the opposite, so we only need to check 3 cases. `{a, b, c, d}, a <= b <= c <= d`, break them up into sums, `{a, a+x, a+x+y, a+x+y+z}, x, y, z >= 0`. Try all of the combinations, `|a+b-c-d| = x+2y+z`, `|a+c-b-d| = z+x`, `|a+d-b-c| = |z-x|`; everything has `z` and `x`, but non-negativity means `|z-x|` is the smallest.

Comment: Or equivalently, pick the sign, `C(4,2)=6`, but the (implied) absolute value means that half of those are degenerate.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the sorted version `|(a + d) - (b + c)|`, where `a ≤ b ≤ c ≤ d`, always works: (1) clearly `c` and `d` are never paired since that would maximise the sum of one side and minimise the other, resulting in the largest possible difference. Now that we know that `c` is on one side and `d` is on the other, clearly we want to add to the larger side (the same or) less than we'll add to the smaller side.